# how to measure the font metrics in javascript? Is there any API available for text metrics like GetCellDescent in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, web

```
function calculateSpanHeight(testLine,font){
          var spanElement = $(document.createElement("span")).css("white-space","pre");
          spanElement[0].id = "tempSpan";
          var spanElement = $(spanElement).html(testLine);
          $(spanElement).appendTo("body");
          $(spanElement).css("font",context.font);
          var testWidth = $("#tempSpan").width();
          var height = $("#tempSpan").height();

          var block = $('<div style="display: inline-block; width: 1px; height: 0px;"></div>');

          var div = $('<div></div>');
          div.append(spanElement, block);

          var body = $('body');
          body.append(div);

          var result = {};

          block.css({ verticalAlign: 'baseline' });
          result.ascent = block.offset().top - spanElement.offset().top;

          block.css({ verticalAlign: 'bottom' });
          result.height = block.offset().top - spanElement.offset().top;

          result.descent = result.height - result.ascent;
          $(div).remove();
          return {"testWidth" : testWidth, "height" : height, "spanElement" : spanElement, "ascent" : result.ascent, "descent" : result.descent};
      }
```

I have used this following code. It is working fine for getting the text width and height values exactly. But i need the text ascent and descent values exactly that is in float value. Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by **text ascent and descent**

Comment: Hi madalin, Thanks for your reply. ascent means the height of the text above the baseline and descent means height of the text below the baseline.Please Refer : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=text+ascent+and+descent+image&tbm=isch&imgil=qxMbxm4SOO7nKM%253A%253B6tuDEh6vjnP4FM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.fampennings.nl%25252Fmaarten%25252Fandroid%25252F08numgrid%25252Findex.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=qxMbxm4SOO7nKM%253A%252C6tuDEh6vjnP4FM%252C_&usg=__d00M90GFiTksd3BHusaNQZXgdI8%3D&biw=1280&bih=598&ved=0ahUKEwicnpyujuHNAhVBOpQKHf9VBcIQyjcINg&ei=nSp-V9zbM8H00AT_q5WQDA#imgrc=qxMbxm4SOO7nKM%3A

Comment: lol why do you need those ??

Comment: I am creating an web application. it is needed for rendering the text in web page.

Comment: do you really need that much control?

Comment: Yes I must need this.

Comment: from my knowledge i can say that this is impossibile

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not "impossible", it's just not built into the browser's available API. JavaScript can parse font files and read the metric data like any other application.

Two libraries that I know of...

## OpenType

Screenshot from http://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html:

[image: screenshot of opentype font inspection]

## Font.js

Screenshot from http://bl.ocks.org/eweitnauer/7324712:

[image: screenshot of font.js font inspection]